# USPS Shipping Method not showing up

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-methods, ups, usps

I have set up two shipping methods.

1. UPS
2. USPS

But USPS is not showing up on the checkout page.

Any idea? I use magento version 1.9.2.4.

Comment: What are all the steps you followed?

Answer (score 0):

As the issue you have posted is not having more information. I have given you the basic solution to fix it. Once you find the exact issue post it back.
There are 2 major possibilities for your issue.

1. Invalid account information : To find and fix this issue, enable the debug mode in the extension and try once again. Now check the debug log, error log and exception log. You can find information in it.
2. Incorrect configuration of the extension : You might have made your maximum package weight less than the product weight, wrong credentials, credentials may be for live account but chosen development in mode. Might have not enabled for checkout.

Note: USPS require the from address to be US. Please check your store settings and confirm it is set to  valid US address.

Answer (score 0):

Check parameters from screenshots for output any information about USPS & make you shipping method is output.

[image: Show Method is not applicable is output USPS with error description. Debug will write more information to log files]

[image: Make sure what USPS is enabled for countries, all shipping method from USPS is selected]

[image: Login and password is correct. Development mode is on]